# Is it possible to put a radio button inside a popconfirm and have the radio button get checked only if the user clicks confirm on the popconfirm?

Tags: antd

I have a a group of radio buttons and I am trying to wrap those radio buttons around a popconfirm element so that the radio button gets checked only if the user selects confirm on the popconfirm. In my code below, I've started fiddling with that idea by wrapping the first radio element inside a popconfirm.

The problem is that when I click a radio button, it gets checked before I've confirmed or canceled the popconfirm. I guess I need to prevent the radio button from checking, and then check it programatically from inside the popconfirm's onConfirm callback. Sadly I couldn't find any examples doing anything like this.

```
  <Radio.Group value={selectedRadio} onChange={this.onChangeRadioButton}>
    <Popconfirm
    title={this.intl.formatMessage({ id: 'common.deviceSelection' })}
    onConfirm={() => console.log('hi')}
    okText={this.intl.formatMessage({ id: 'common.confirm' })}
    cancelText={this.intl.formatMessage({ id: 'common.cancel' })}
    >
      <Radio value={actions.restartApp}>
        <IntlMessages id="configuration.bedsCarts.actions.restartApp" />
      </Radio>
    </Popconfirm>
      <Radio value={actions.restartOs}>
        <IntlMessages id="configuration.bedsCarts.actions.restartOs" />
      </Radio>
      <Radio value={actions.restartHardware}>
        <IntlMessages id="configuration.bedsCarts.actions.restartHardware" />
      </Radio>
      <Radio value={actions.updateVersion}>
        <IntlMessages id="configuration.bedsCarts.actions.updateVersion" />
      </Radio>
      <Radio value={actions.updateNetworkCertificate}>
        <IntlMessages id="configuration.bedsCarts.actions.updateNetworkCertificate" />
      </Radio>
      <Radio value={actions.moveSystemDevices}>
        <IntlMessages id="configuration.bedsCarts.actions.moveSystemDevices" />
      </Radio>
  </Radio.Group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can you write the Popconfirm processing logic manually. For example:

1. Create a variable to track the status of Popconfirm.
2. If a button is pressed that requires confirmation, set the value for `selectedRadio` only if the user clicked the consent button.
3. If user confirms action, then set the `selectedRadio` and reset `isConfirmed` to `false`.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Radio, Popconfirm } from "antd";

export const MyComponent = () => {
  // 1
  const [isConfirmed, setIsConfirmed] = useState(false);
  const [selectedRadio, setSelectedRadio] = useState();

  return (
    <Radio.Group
      value={selectedRadio}
      onChange={(e) => {
        // 2
        if (!isConfirmed && e.target.value === "actions.restartApp") {
          return;
        }

        setSelectedRadio(e.target.value);
        // 3
        setIsConfirmed(false);
      }}
    >
      <Popconfirm
        title={"common.deviceSelection"}
        onConfirm={() => {
          setIsConfirmed(true);
          setSelectedRadio("actions.restartApp");
        }}
        okText={"common.confirm"}
        cancelText={"common.cancel"}
      >
        <Radio
          value={"actions.restartApp"}
          onClick={(e) => {
            console.log(isConfirmed);
            if (!isConfirmed) {
              e.preventDefault();
              return;
            }
          }}
        >
          <div>configuration.bedsCarts.actions.restartApp</div>
        </Radio>
      </Popconfirm>
      <Radio value={"actions.restartOs"}>
        <div>configuration.bedsCarts.actions.restartOs1</div>
      </Radio>
      <Radio value={"actions.restartHardware"}>
        <div>configuration.bedsCarts.actions.restartOs2</div>
      </Radio>
      <Radio value={"actions.updateVersion"}>
        <div>configuration.bedsCarts.actions.restartOs2</div>
      </Radio>
      <Radio value={"actions.updateNetworkCertificate"}>
        <div>configuration.bedsCarts.actions.restartOs4</div>
      </Radio>
      <Radio value={"actions.moveSystemDevices"}>
        <div>configuration.bedsCarts.actions.restartOs5</div>
      </Radio>
    </Radio.Group>
  );
};
```

DEMO: https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-forked-6h5zp?file=/MyComponent.jsx